# Property behaves differently when not wrapped in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I don’t understand very well how this JS function gets the data. This is the first variation of my code:

```
function iReceived(msg) {
              console.log(msg.data);
          };
            var rest = $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType:'jsonp',
                   url: "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/",
                   data: {"modelName": "Address",
                        "calledMethod": "getCities",
                        "methodProperties":{}, 
                         "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
                success:  function(e) { iReceived(e) }, 

            });
```

The function `iReceived` prints the data that it gets. But in the second variation:

```
function iReceived(msg) {
              console.log(msg.data);
          };
            var rest = $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType:'jsonp',
                   url: "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/",
                   data: {"modelName": "Address",
                        "calledMethod": "getCities",
                        "methodProperties":{}, 
                         "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
                success:   iReceived(e) , 

            });
```

the function returns `undefined`. Please, tell me why this variantion works a different way.

Comment: `function(e) { iReceived(e) }` is a function, `iReceived(e)` is `undefined` (it calls `iReceived` and uses the return value — `undefined` because nothing is returned). The value of the `success` property should be a function.

Comment: Because you're calling `iReceived` immediately instead of setting it as the callback. Doing `success: iReceived(e)` is just like writing `iReceived(e)` on a line by itself.

Comment: Before anyone comments as to the specific duplicate, please be aware that `setTimeout` is a red-herring as to the actual issue here, which is calling a function instead of passing a function. The solution is absolutely the same, and this is a common problem.

Comment: @Xufox
>The value of the success property should be a function.
And the  success  "feeds" his data to the function, am i right understand?

Comment: @Ogurchik Internally the success property is called (if it is a function) with some parameters. The parameters contain the data.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you are able to pass a function as argument to other functions just by referring it by its name with no parentheses.

So you need to pass a reference to the success callback. If you pass `iReceived()` it is immediately executed and not what you expect here.

The first example works because you passed an anonymous function to the success callback which is executed right after your request is done. While  the anonymous function is executed it is able to run your function with the loaded data.

#### Further reading on this topic

- http://nsono.net/javascript-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference
- https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

#### Code

```
function iReceived(msg) {
  console.log(msg.data);
};

var rest = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/",
  data: {
    "modelName": "Address",
    "calledMethod": "getCities",
    "methodProperties": {},
    "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  success: iReceived,

});
```

Comment: Oh, oh honestly say i didn't wait such answer. No  a function, and reference to the function, hmm, this is unexpectedly. Thanks for your answer.